# Haskell Network.HTTP.Client withResponse headers

Tags: haskell, http-headers

I'm using `Network.HTTP.Client` and trying to read headers of a streaming response.

I see [from documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.5/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:withResponse) that the type signature is:

```
withResponse :: Request -> Manager -> (Response BodyReader -> IO a) -> IO a
```

Defined as:

```
withResponse req man f = bracket (responseOpen req man) responseClose f
```

And I'm trying to correctly define (\f -> do stuff) to be able to just show all the headers in the response.

```
getheaders ::  String -> IO ()
getheaders url = do
  man <- newManager tlsManagerSettings
  req' <- parseUrlThrow url
  putStrLn url
  let req = req' { responseTimeout = Just 1000000}
  withResponse req man $ (\res -> do
    (r _) <- res
    putStrLn $ show r
    )
```

I understand \res is actually:

```
(Response BodyReader -> IO a)
```

How can I extract the headers from that?

```
responseHeaders :: Response body -> ResponseHeaders
```

Any tips also on how you'd investigate these types in ghci also appreciated.

Comment: A nice trick is to factor out the function, give it a name and an `undefined` body and have ghci confirm the type. You could also use `:i` e.g. for finding out what `BodyReader` or `ResponseHeaders` are and where they're from. (Not that you would need the former for now, as `responseHeaders` accepts any Response content via `body`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`responseHeaders`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.16/http-client/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:responseHeaders) accessor functor. You had the right intuition with the type signature. In fact, [searching for that type signature on Stackage's Hoogle yields this function at the first result](https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.16/hoogle?q=Response+body+-%3E+ResponseHeaders).

With your original code, you're looking for something like:

```
withResponse req man $ print . responseHeaders
```

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Snoyman.  I see from that pattern how I can go nuts on my debug and do:   `withResponse req man $ (\x -> do 
  (print . responseStatus) x
  (print . responseHeaders) x )` etc.  Thank you!